# Set marginRight doesn't works

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

i want to put two scrollview with the margin, i have two ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout. On left "android:marginLeft" works

```
     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#fff" >
```

But on Right.. the scrollview is total on Left

```
     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="#fff" >
```

Comment: You should probably tell it to `alignParentRight` if you want it on the right side of the screen.

Comment: so you want two scroll views, one on the left and one on the right side of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" >
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="100dp">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" >
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways as @Geobits say. IF you are using A RelativeLayout you can also tell to each child view how to align like :

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#fff" >
    </ScrollView>
     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:background="#fff" >
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set alignParentRight="true" .Hope it works.